# Prove $\displaystyle{\not}{\nabla}^2=\nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu}-R/4$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, dirac-matrices

I am trying to show  $\displaystyle{\not}{\nabla}^2=\nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu}+R/4$ where $R$ is Ricci scalar. $\nabla_{\mu}$ is covariant derivative for spinor:
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\omega^{ab}_{\mu}S_{ab},~~S_{ab}=\frac{1}{4}[\gamma_a,\gamma_b]
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle{\not}{\nabla}=\gamma^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}.
\end{equation}
Here $\gamma_a$'s with Latin indices are usual gamma matrices with $\{\gamma_a,\gamma_b\}=2\eta_{ab}$, $\eta$ is the metric of flat spactime. $\gamma^{\mu}=e^{\mu}_a\gamma^{a}$, where $e^{\mu}_a$ is [tetrad basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_formalism) coefficient.

First I can isolate $\nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu}$ first:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\displaystyle{\not}{\nabla}^2&=\gamma^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}\\
&=(\nabla_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}+[\gamma^{\mu},\nabla_{\mu}])\gamma^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}\\
&=\nabla_{\mu}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}+[\gamma^{\mu},\nabla_{\mu}]\gamma^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}\\
&=\nabla_{\mu}\nabla^{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\nabla_{\mu}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]\nabla_{\nu}+[\gamma^{\mu},\nabla_{\mu}]\gamma^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
From here I am unable to continue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: flat metric really ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed is to define $\gamma^\mu = \gamma^a e_a^\mu$ and note that
$$
(\partial_\mu + \textstyle{\frac 12}  \sigma^{ab} \omega_{ab\mu})\gamma^\nu
= \gamma^\nu (\partial_\mu + \textstyle{\frac 12}  \sigma^{ab} \omega_{ab\mu})- \gamma^\lambda {\Gamma^\nu}_{\lambda\mu}
$$
so that
$$
({D})^2= \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu(D_\mu D _\nu- {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}D_\lambda).
$$
If the connection is torsion-free, so ${\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}$ is symmetric in $\mu,\nu$,  we can  proceed as follows:
$$
 ({ D})^2=  \textstyle{\frac 12}  \{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\} (D_\mu D_\nu- {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}D_\lambda)  +\textstyle{\frac 12} [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu] D_\mu D_\nu \\
=  g^{\mu\nu} (D_{\mu}D_{\nu}-  {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}D_\lambda) +\textstyle{\frac 14} [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu] [D_{\mu}, D_{\nu}].\nonumber\\
=   g^{\mu\nu} (D_{\mu}D_{\nu}-  {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}D_\lambda) + \textstyle{\frac 14} [\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu] \textstyle{\frac 12}\sigma^{ab} R_{ab\mu\nu}\nonumber\\
=   g^{\mu\nu} (D_{\mu}D_{\nu}-  {\Gamma^\lambda}_{\nu\mu}D_\lambda) + \textstyle{\frac 12}\sigma^{ab}\sigma^{cd}R_{abcd}\nonumber\\
= \frac 1{\sqrt{g}} D_\mu \sqrt{g}g^{\mu\nu}  D_\nu + \textstyle{\frac 12}\sigma^{ab}\sigma^{cd}R_{abcd}.\nonumber
$$
The first term in the last-but-one line  is often just written as $g^{\mu\nu} \nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu \equiv \nabla^2$, with the use of $\nabla$, the covariant derivative acting on the components of spinors and/or tensors as appropriate,  tacitly    implying the extra Christoffel symbol.

We can also use the same technique to show that
$$
 ({D})^2= \gamma^a \gamma^b(D_a D_b -
{\omega^c}_{ba}D_c).
 $$
We  then use
$$
[\nabla_{{\bf e}_a}, \nabla_{{\bf e}_b}]- \nabla_{[{\bf e}_a,{\bf e}_b]}=  \textstyle{\frac 12}  \sigma^{cd} R_{cdab}.
$$
with the torsion-free condition giving the first equality in
$$
[{\bf e}_a,{\bf e}_b]=\nabla_{{\bf e}_a} {\bf e}_b-  \nabla_{{\bf e}_b} {\bf e}_a= {\bf e}_c ({\omega^c}_{ba} -{\omega^c}_{ab}).
$$
We find
$$
 ({D})^2=\delta^{ab}(D_a D_b -
{\omega^c}_{ba}D_c) +  \textstyle{\frac 12}\sigma^{ab}\sigma^{cd}R_{abcd}.
 $$

We can now use the symmetries  of the Riemann tensor to  simplify the curvature term: Consider $\gamma^a \gamma^b\gamma^c\gamma^d R_{abcd}$. By antisymmetry properties of $R_{abcd}$ we know  that $a\ne b$ and $c\ne d$. Suppose that $b$ is not equal to either $c$ or $d$, then we can write
$$
\gamma^a \gamma^b\gamma^c\gamma^d R_{abcd} =
\textstyle{\frac 1{3}} (\gamma^a \gamma^b\gamma^c\gamma^d +\gamma^a \gamma^c\gamma^d\gamma^b +\gamma^a \gamma^d\gamma^b\gamma^c) R_{abcd}\nonumber\\
= \textstyle{\frac 1{3}} \gamma^a \gamma^b\gamma^c\gamma^d (R_{abcd}+R_{adbc}+ R_{acdb}) \nonumber\\
=0,\nonumber
$$
by the first Bianchi identity for the Riemann curvature of a torsion-free connection.  To get a non-zero answer, therefore, there are two possibilities: $b$ must equal $c$ (and not $d$), or it must equal $d$ (and not $c$). Thus
$$
\gamma^a \gamma^b\gamma^c\gamma^d R_{abcd} = \gamma^a  \gamma^c R_{abbc}- \gamma^a \gamma^c R_{abcb} \nonumber\\
= -2 \gamma^a\gamma^c R_{ac}\nonumber\\
=-2 R\nonumber
$$
where $R_{ab} = R_{acbc}$ is the (symmetric) Ricci tensor, and $R=R_{aa}$ is the scalar curvature.

We thus have the  identity
$$
({D})^2= \nabla^2 -  \frac 14 R,
$$
where $$
\nabla^2\equiv\frac 1{\sqrt{g}} D_\mu \sqrt{g}g^{\mu\nu}  D_\nu
$$
is the *rough*, or *connection*  laplacian acting on spinors.

Although named for  Lichnerowicz' work in  1963, the identity is due to Schroedinger: E. Schroedinger, *Diracsches Elektron im Schwerefeld I*, Sitzungsber. Preuss.  Akad.  Wiss., Phys.  Math. Kl. 11,  (1932) 105-128. His paper available online [here](https://edition-open-sources.org/media/sources/10/15/sources10chap13.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed calculation. So it seems $\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}D_{\mu}\sqrt{g} g^{\mu \nu}D_{\nu}$ is denoted by $\nabla_{mu}\nabla^{\mu}$ and is not equal to the real $\nabla_{mu}\nabla^{\mu}$?

Comment: $D^\mu$ acts on spinors and so contains the spin connection. The usual Laplacian on scalars which is written as $\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu= g^{-1/2}\partial_\mu g^{1/2}g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu$  does not contain the spin connection.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still a little bit confused. If $D$ is acting on spinor, $\sqrt{g}$ can't pass through the $D_{\mu}$, so usually $\sqrt{g}^{-1}D_{\mu}\sqrt{g}g^{\mu \nu}D_{\nu}$ is not equal to $D_{\mu}g^{\mu \nu}D_{\nu}$ which is $D_{\mu}D^{\mu}$. Am I right?

Comment: $D_\mu$ has a derivative so $\sqrt g$ can never "pass through" it. Instead $g^{-1/2}\partial_\mu g^{1/2}= {\Gamma^a}_{a\mu}$ provides the extra Christoffel symbol that is needed because $\partial^\mu f$ are the components of a contravariant tensor.